# deleting text in textfiles does not work need advice

Tags: python

my problem is that i am trying to delete text in the textfile once it has been used just to say this doesn't work i have tried it enough time and i have almost given up hope

```
import time
import random
Points = 0
Num = 4
V = 0
songNames = []
songArtists = []

def Game1(Points, Num, V):
    if V == 1:
        while True:
            with open("textfile.txt", "r") as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                with open("textfile.txt", "w") as f:
                    for line in lines:
                        if line.strip("\n") != (songNum):
                            f.write()


            with open("textfile2.txt", "r") as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                with open("textfile2.txt", "w") as f:
                    for line in lines:
                        if line.strip("\n") != (songNum):
                            f.write()

            time.sleep(1)
            s1 = open("textfile.txt","r")

            for line in s1:
                line = line.strip("\n")
                songNames.append(line)
            s1.close()                   
            s2 = open("textfile2.txt","r")

            for line in s2:
                 line = line.strip("\n")
                 songArtists.append(line)
            s2.close()                                            
            while Num > 0:
                songNum = random.randint(0,Num)
                songPicked = songNames[songNum]


                for index in(songPicked):
                    print(index)
                    break
                songPicked2 = songArtists[songNum]
                print(songPicked2)   
                Answer1 = input("What is the name of this song? ")
                if Answer1 == songPicked:
                    print ("Correct!")
                    V = 1                        

                    Num = Num - 1
                    Points = Points + 3

                    if Num == 0:
                        print ("The game is over")
                        print ("You got",Points,"point(s)")
                        Authorisation(Points, Num, V)
                    else:
                        Game1(Points, Num, V)
                else:
                    print ("Incorrect! Try Again!")
                    Answer1 = input("What is the name of this song? ")
                    if Answer1 == songPicked:
                        print ("Correct!")

                        Num = Num - 1
                        Points = Points + 1
                        if Num == 0:
                            print ("The game is over")
                            print ("You got",Points,"point(s)")
                            Authorisation(Points, Num, V)
                        else:
                            Game1(Points, Num, V)

                    else:
                        print ("Incorrect! Game over!") 
                        print ("You got",Points,"point(s)")
                        Authorisation(Points, Num, V)
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        s1 = open("textfile.txt","r")

        for line in s1:
            line = line.strip("\n")
            songNames.append(line)
        s1.close()                   
        s2 = open("textfile2.txt","r")

        for line in s2:
            line = line.strip("\n")
            songArtists.append(line)
        s2.close()                                            
        while Num > 0:
            songNum = random.randint(0,Num)
            songPicked = songNames[songNum]


            for index in(songPicked):
                print(index)
                break
            songPicked2 = songArtists[songNum]
            print(songPicked2)   
            Answer1 = input("What is the name of this song? ")
            if Answer1 == songPicked:
                print ("Correct!")


                Num = Num - 1
                Points = Points + 3

                if Num == 0:
                    print ("The game is over")
                    print ("You got",Points,"point(s)")
                    Authorisation(Points, Num, V)
                else:
                    Game1(Points, Num, V)
            else:
                print ("Incorrect! Try Again!")
                Answer1 = input("What is the name of this song? ")
                if Answer1 == songPicked:
                    print ("Correct!")

                    Num = Num - 1
                    Points = Points + 1
                    if Num == 0:
                        print ("The game is over")
                        print ("You got",Points,"point(s)")
                        Authorisation(Points, Num, V)
                    else:
                        Game1(Points, Num, V)

                else:
                    print ("Incorrect! Game over!") 
                    print ("You got",Points,"point(s)")
                    Authorisation(Points, Num, V)



def Authorisation(Points, Num, V):
        V = 0
        Num = 4
        Points = 0
        AuInput = input("Enter an authorised account login ")

        if AuInput == ("Moderator") or AuInput == ("Admin"):
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Authorising...")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Welcome",AuInput,"to [Music Game] Alpha 1.0")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Alpha Test")
            Game1(Points, Num, V)
        else:
            print("Unauthorised account login")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Please Try Again")
            time.sleep(1)
            Authorisation(Points, Num, V)



Authorisation(Points, Num, V)
```

this is all my code

Comment: ``"this doesn't work"`` is not helping us to help you. Please provide a [mcve] and the full error stack.

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, please add it to the question. Please try to explain what you're trying to do clearly

Comment: there is no error message it play through as its suppose to but when it asks the question it can ask the same one twice

Comment: the answers and questions are stored in textfiles

Answer (score 0):

You're doing

```
f.write()
```

This has no effect - you're not *writing* anything. Instead, you want

```
f.write(line)
```

which will accomplish your goal of reading in the file, filtering it for lines that meet your pattern, and writing only those lines back to the file.

Comment: I have implemented this and it still shows up twice

Answer (score 0):

well first off the opening a file for reading then opening the same file for writing can be combined you can read and write at the same time if you just use

```
with open("textfile.txt", "r+") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                if line.strip("\n") != (songNum):
                   f.write()
```

just to shorten it up a bit

Then when you call f.write() you're not actually doing anything if you call f.write(line) then your actually writing something to the the .write() function actually needs something passed in to write to the file